# Can't post on a protected question with 101 reputation

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, protected-questions

I'm trying to post an answer to [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32897/another-idiom-for-computer-programmers) question. I have 101 reputation (with the bonus for being trusted on other SO sites), but it is still telling me that I can't answer it because it's protected, requiring 10 rep. I clearly have 10 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protected questions don't factor in the +100 reputation from the association bonus. In order to answer protected questions, you need to have earned at least +10 reputation elsewhere on this site specifically, via questions, answers, edits, et cetera.

For more information, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170937/why-is-association-bonus-ignored-when-trying-to-answer-a-protected-question) on Meta SE. ([This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati) talks about rewording "protection" for clarity.)

Comment: I looked into this the other day, because I noticed someone unable to answer, and it bothered me.  I found this, as well which places it out of the realm of meta questions and into the actual site help page portions: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user